# How can I spread a wallpaper image across multiple desktops?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-customization, compiz

I'm looking for a way to strecth my wallpaper across multiple virtual desktops (workspaces).

How do I achieve that in Ubuntu. Is there an option in Compiz for that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861037) on the Ubuntu forums... The specific fix is to `Download the 'Gnome Tweak Tool', now called 'Advanced Setting' in the Ubuntu Software Centre. Once installed, run it and look for 'Desktop'.  Turn off 'Have file manager handle the desktop'.`